# aChartEngine android api time chart PointerStyle design issues

Tags: android, achartengine

Current time chart Design
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWkbK.jpg]

Desired time chart Design

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppAS.jpg]

how do i achieve this kind of PointerStyle design in achartengine api for android? please take a look at the two picture. i guess the picture explain everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the points with their own color, not with any random one:

```
renderer.setFillPoints(true);
```